# Adding value to the paragraph "Highest Score "

Tags: javascript

I have wrote a quick reaction game test, but I want to display the best score(lowest time) of reaction of the people who play.

I have wrote this function but it show only true or false and I want that it show a value (numbers).

```js
function appearAfterDelay() {
  setTimeout(makeShapeApper, Math.random() * 2000);
}

appearAfterDelay();

document.getElementById("shape").onclick = function() {

  document.getElementById("shape").style.display = "none";
  
  var end = new Date().getTime();
  var timeTaken = (end - start) / 1000;
  document.getElementById("timeTaken").innerHTML = timeTaken + "s";

  if (timeTaken < 700) {
    var score = timeTaken < 0.7;
    document.getElementById("lowestTime").innerHTML = score + "s"
  }

  appearAfterDelay();
}
```

Comment: Can you please share your relevant html code?

Comment: `var score = timeTaken < 0.7;` `<` is "less than", so if `timeTaken` is less than 0.7, `score` will be true; otherwise, false.

Comment: yes it'sa boolean, but i want it to show the number

Comment: Um if it's Boolean how can it display number???

Comment: idk infact i want to know how i can make it to show numbers

Answer (score 0):

`var score = timeTaken < 0.7;` Will always evaluate as a boolean. So if you assign that to innerHTML it will be true or false. Probably meant something like `var score = timeTaken {* or /} 0.7;`

```
if (timeTaken < 700) {
   var score = timeTaken < 0.7;
   document.getElementById("lowestTime").innerHTML = score + "s"
}
```